# copy can't work when i use Runtime.getRuntime().exec to merge mp3

Tags: java, cmd, merge, runtime, exec

I have two mp3 file and i want to merge them,i use the cmd like this:

```
C:\Users\57477\Desktop>copy /b /y 1.mp3+2.mp3 3.mp3
```

It's effective,but when i use in java,it can't work

```
String[] cmd = { "cmd.exe", "/c", "C:", "&&", "cd", "C:\\Users\\57477\\Desktop", "&&", "copy", "/b", "/y","1.mp3+2.mp3", "3.mp3" };
    // this cmd also can't work
    String cmd2 = "cmd.exe /c C: && cd C:\\Users\\57477\\Desktop && copy /b 1.mp3+2.mp3 3.mp3";
    Runtime run = null;
    try {
        run = Runtime.getRuntime();
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Process p = run.exec(cmd);
        // 释放进程
        p.getOutputStream().close();
        p.getInputStream().close();
        p.getErrorStream().close();
        p.waitFor();
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(" convert success, costs:" + (end - start) + "ms");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        run.freeMemory();
    }
```

If i just copy one file,it can work,like this:

```
String[] cmd = { "cmd.exe", "/c", "C:", "&&", "cd", "C:\\Users\\57477\\Desktop", "&&", "copy", "/b", "/y","1.mp3", "3.mp3" };
    // this cmd is effective
String cmd2 = "cmd.exe /c C: && cd C:\\Users\\57477\\Desktop && copy /b 1.mp3 3.mp3";
String cmd3 = "cmd.exe /c copy /b /y C:\\Users\\57477\\Desktop\\1.mp3 C:\\Users\\57477\\Desktop\\3.mp3";
```

I try to use start command,like this:

```
cmd /c start copy /b /y C:\\Users\\57477\\Desktop\\1.mp3+C:\\Users\\57477\\Desktop\\2.mp3 C:\\Users\\57477\\Desktop\\3.mp3
```

It will open a window to run this command and it's work,but the window cann't not auto close.

I think it should be the '+' interfere the command,but i don't know how to fix it,i use google and bing and baidu,use about one day,also fail.

At your convenience, would you please help me? Any help or suggestion will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When I slept, I found the answer...i reversed the code like this:

```
p.waitFor();
p.getOutputStream().close();
p.getInputStream().close();
p.getErrorStream().close();
```

It's work now......